# Pass a part of perl to bc

Tags: linux, perl, replace, bc

I'm trying to write a command that gives me some information about a linux system. The command should be a one liner. It should represent the total amount of interrupts, processes and context-switches.

I'm quite new to the linux world, so this isn't an easy thin for me. So far, I found this:

```
cat /proc/stat | grep -E 'ctxt|intr|processes' | \
 perl -nle 'if ($line == /^intr (.*)/) {print $_} else {print $1}'
```

The problem is in the last part, the else. I'm not interessed in the value of $1, but I should know the sum of the items in $1.

$1 should contain something like:

```
8522774 17 6 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 1435117 21 103 0 84742 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But I've no idea how I could get the sum of all these numbers. I believe I should pass it to bc, but I've no idea how to manage this.

Comment: That's a redundant use of `cat`. Perhaps you should show input and expected output. That will make this about 10 times easier to help you with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your one-liner:

```
cat /proc/stat | grep -E 'ctxt|intr|processes' | \
perl -nle 'if ($line == /^intr (.*)/) {print $_} else {print $1}'
```

The problem with this line is that perl has no implicit variable `$line`, it is called `$_`. Also, the regex is applied to strings with the binding operator `=~`, not the numeric equality operator `==`. Your if-statement is reversed, if the regex doesn't match, you don't want to print `$1`, because that is the string that is captured by parentheses in your last regex.

You also do not need to use `cat` or `grep`, since perl can handle this just fine.

```
perl -nlwe 'if (/ctxt|processes/) { print } 
            elsif (/^intr (.*)/ { print $1 }' /proc/stat
```

This one-liner *should* do exactly what your line did, in that it "greps" the lines that match `ctxt|intr|processes`, and prints only the match for the "intr" lines.

If you want to print the sum of certain numbers, which feels like a whole new question to me, you can make use of the `sum()` subroutine from the [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) module in perl. E.g.:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -nlwe 'if (/ctxt|processes/) { print } 
            elsif (/^intr (.*)/ { print sum split ' ', $1 }' /proc/stat
```

In this case, you'll need to rely on your captured string to contain only numbers. `sum()` takes a list of numbers, which is why we need to split the input.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
awk '/^intr/ {for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) sum+=$i; print "intr",sum}
     /^processes|ctxt/ {print}' /proc/stat
```

You usually don't have to call `bc` from `perl`, but maybe there is a reason for your overall approach being  "the more processes, the better".

Answer (score -3):

```
cat /proc/stat | grep -E 'ctxt|intr|processes' | 
    perl -nle 'if ($line == /^intr (.*)/) {print $_} else {print $1}' | 
    sed 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but the perl part is still broken, you still have a redundant use of cat, and you tack on yet another process on the end instead of handling it with perl.